# Fatal error: "Class JController" not found in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to update the Joomla version on one of the website I managed.

I downloaded the package to upgrade to Joomla 1.5.25 (if my memory's good). I did a test on a dev website and everything worked well.

Now, when I apply the update to the current website, i receive the error : Fatal error: "Class JController" not found in ***/components/com_content/controller.php "

The line 
    jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
is there.

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What version were you upgrading from? How did you apply the upgrade - ftping the files up to the server manually?

Comment: Make sure, that the file /joomla/application/component/controller.php is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to upload the files again via FTP client. Sometimes files don't transfer properly or at all. Also make sure you downloaded the correct upgrade package related to your previous version.

Comment: Actually, I had to upload the tar.gz and extract from the server via SSH. Transfering extracted file via FTP didn't worked